# Apache HttpClientContext Serialization

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is there any elegant way to serialize the apache `HttpClientContext` object?

In order to share one same `HttpClientContext` object among multiple `HttpClient`s in different period, I need to serialize it and save it into a central database every time an `HttpClient` has modified it. The connection manager and other connection concerned fields in `HttpClientContext` can be ignored, while the cookie store, user agent and some other HTTP concerned fields should be able to read and write among multiple `HttpClient`s. Is there any elegant way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you think this is a good approach ? If you need shared cookies: share them. But I wouldn't share the technical context.

Comment: @Marged Your words make sense. But I wonder besides cookie store, if there is any other field in `HttpClientContext` which should also be shared to make multiple `HttpClient`s in a consecutive environment.

Comment: @Marged For instance, I just found that `http.request-config` in `HttpClientContext` should also be shared...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really do *not* want to serialize content of the HTTP context indiscriminately, as it is very likely to contain user creds in clear text. Not to mention that some context attributes may simply be not serializable. The only thing is should be serializing is cookie store

Comment: Well, I see... You are right, I should not serialize the entire `HttpClientContext` due to the user creds and some other things. Thanks.